# How to fill new values in a data frame column based on some condition from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, if-statement

How to fill new values in a dataframe based on some condition from other column

For eg. I want to fill the rows which have the time as 11:30 in **y** column with value 1 in regressor column, while those dates having time 11:25 should be filled with value 2 in regressor column.

How to do this?

The type of `input_df["ds"]` column is `pandas.core.series.Series`

input_df

```
            ds             y    regressor
0   2019-10-04 11:30:00    a       0
1   2019-10-04 11:35:00    b       0
2   2019-10-04 11:40:00    c       0
3   2019-10-04 11:25:00    d       0
4   2019-10-04 11:50:00    e       0
.
.
.
n   2019-14-04 11:50:00    f       0
```

output_df

```
            ds             y    regressor
0   2019-10-04 11:30:00    a       1
1   2019-10-04 11:35:00    b       0
2   2019-10-04 11:40:00    c       0
3   2019-10-04 11:25:00    d       2
4   2019-10-04 11:50:00    e       0
.
.
.
n   2019-14-04 11:50:00    f       0

'''
```

Comment: How many values are there to check for? What have you tried? Have you read the pandas docs? This seems like pandas 101. Not only that, but these kinds of questions have been asked dozens and dozens of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a nested `np.where` which acts as an if-else function:

```
input_df['regressor'] = np.where(input_df['ds'].dt.time=='11:30:00',
                                 1, 
                                 np.where(input_df['ds'].dt.time=='11:25:00',
                                          2, 
                                          input_df['regressor']))
```

Comment: How is this better than using `.loc[]`, `.map`, etc.?

Comment: @AMC To me it is more intuitive, yet as performance is concerned I don't know which one is better. Could be interesting checking it

Comment: What do you mean by intuitive? Once there are 4+ conditions/values, this becomes a complete nightmare of nesting.

Comment: Yes but it is not the case here. Also if you have lots of conditions how do you use map? IMHO they both get messy

Comment: For this particular case, I was thinking of using `.map()` with a dictionary. Keeping a dictionary definition clean is easy, since you can very naturally put one key:value pair per line.